# how to use Thick box to asp.net web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

Hello friends I m new for this thick box so some one can help me ...........

Comment: Read this: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html
It will help you in your future use of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Thickbox, or any other jQuery or MooTools based pop-up is JavaScript based and hence runs client side. Because of that it needs to sit in the HTML element of your page (this is the bit in the source view of Visual Studio), as opposed to the server side c# code in the .cs file. The fact that you're building the site with asp.net is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I know as you say its little bit difficult to work with c# and source code of asp.net but yesterday i just try to do that and hope fully its work very nicely and thanks for your reply and 
if I want to use shadow (Opening the Image in zoom view) effect for the my image gallery web site then what is the next procedure for that in Javascript